# How to execute arangodb transaction in php after redis transaction is comfirmed?

Tags: php, redis, arangodb, arangodb-php

I need to put some data in `arangodb` and `redis` at the same time but I need some help on how to do it.

Something like this:

```
global $connection;
        $time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $document = array(
            "replyTo" => $replyTo,
            "user_key"    => $uid,
            'view_option' =>$view,
            'topics'=> $topics,
            'type'=>$type,
            'time'=>$time,
            'content'=>$content,
            'comments'=>0,
            'upvotes'=>0,
            'downvotes'=>0,
            'age_res'=>$agerestriction
        );
        $query="INSERT @doc IN `posts` RETURN NEW";
        $statement = new Statement(
            $connection,
            array(
                "query"     => $query,
                "bindVars"  => array("doc" => $document)
            )
        );
        //waiting for redis transaction to be done
        $statement->execute();
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already. The "please write some code for me" type of questions is usually frowned upon at SO. You should probably take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Best regards

Comment: I changed it a bit, thank you @YakovL

Comment: What are you using arangodb for? is it as a Graph DB?

Comment: As a document store and graph database, yes.